# How to delete object from an array of objects having relations with each arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, algorithm, recursion

This Object have relationship as: **childOne** > **childTwo** > **childThree** > **childFour** > **childFive** > **childSix**.

```
{
  "parentObj": {
    "childOne": [
      {
        "name": "A",
        "id": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "B",
        "id": "2"
      }
    ],
    "childTwo": [
      {
        "name": "AB",
        "parent_id": "1",
        "id": "11"
      },
      {
        "name": "DE",
        "parent_id": "2",
        "id": "22"
      }
    ],
    "childThree": [
      {
        "name": "ABC",
        "parent_id": "22",
        "id": "111"
      },
      {
        "name": "DEF",
        "parent_id": "11",
        "id": "222"
      }
    ],
    "childFour": [
      {
        "name": "ABCD",
        "parent_id": "111",
        "id": "1111"
      },
      {
        "name": "PQRS",
        "parent_id": "111",
        "id": "2222"
      }
    ],
    "childFive": [
      {
        "name": "FGRGF",
        "parent_id": "1111",
        "id": "11111"
      },
      {
        "name": "ASLNJ",
        "parent_id": "1111",
        "id": "22222"
      },
      {
        "name": "ASKJA",
        "parent_id": "1111",
        "id": "33333"
      }
    ],
    "childSix": [
      {
        "name": "SDKJBS",
        "parent_id": "11111",
        "id": "111111"
      },
      {
        "name": "ASKLJB",
        "parent_id": "11111",
        "id": "222222"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there any way to delete an item by ID and the objects which are associated with that particular ID should get deleted(i.e., If I do `delete parentObj.childTwo[1]`, then all the related object beneath it should also gets deleted).

Looping manually is too bad code, and generate bugs. There must be better ways of dealing with this kind of problems like recursion, or other.

Comment: Short answer: no, there is no magic way to get it to understand your structure and recursively delete objects. You'll need to write the code (just write it well, and test it - then it wont be "buggy")

Comment: If you manually define the parent-child order with titles like this, instead of reflecting the order in the data structure, there won't be a free lunch. You have to use this information "`childOne > childTwo > childThree > childFour > childFive > childSix`" one way or another.

Comment: @Mehdi I'm getting the object key as parameter to the method. It can be of any level.

Comment: So, @S.Negi are you saying, an item in parentObj.childOne might have a key like "childFive" with value like "44444" for example?

Comment: How would the delete function look like? `removeItem("childOne",obj.parentElement)`?

Comment: @HMR removeItem("Objectname:childFour", "key:ID:4444"), So if the objects below childFour are using key:4444 (and objects beneath it vice versa) those objects should also be deleted.

Comment: @S.Negi that is awful parameters - you need to string mash to get the useful information from them.

Comment: @Jamiec each object has a reference to their upper object except for the top 1. Suppose if I want to remove object:childThree with id:111, So the objects that are referencing to the id 111, will get removed (and other objects which reference to the removed item).

Comment: @S.Negi I know - have you seen my answer? IT achieves the same without the crazy string-based parameters

Comment: You do know that ES is case sensitive right? In your example objects have `id` but in your answer you're talking about `ID` is 4444 in your answer a number and in your example data a string as well?

Comment: @HMR It was to emphasize the key only. I wasn't meant it the other way. ;p

Comment: Are the id values guaranteed to be unique across the whole object, or can there be the same id values, but occurring in different "childXXX" arrays?

Comment: @trincot It'll be unique per object.

Comment: OK, another question: is it guaranteed that the reference to a node's parent is *always* in a property called "childXXX", where XXX is one less than the name of the array where the node is listed? This is the case in your example. Just want to be sure it is always like that. Or could the array in "childFive" have nodes that have a "childTwo" property?

Comment: @trincot based on the parent id, actually these all are checkboxes. So suppose you check childB then childC with properties will be added to the list. if childC is selected then all the childD with parentID will be added.

Comment: The mention of checkboxes complicates it -- I am lost. Can you please answer which of the two scenarios I described is true/false? Otherwise put: is it possible for two nodes in the *same* array to have a different name for their "childXXX" property? Example: in "childX", there would be a node with "childY" and another with "childZ" (where Y != Z). Is that possible or not?

Comment: @trincot I've changed a bit in the object, I hope now the relation between the objects are clear.

Comment: Oh... that changes the question... and I had just answered based on your previous structure. Please have a look.  Does this mean we could propose a different structure all together? Because, as others have stated, your structure is really not well suited for such manipulation. I now note that the newly introduced `parent_id` presupposes that `id` values are unique throughout the object, which I had asked you, but you answered they were only unique per object. Maybe I misunderstood "per object"....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no efforts were shown on their behalf

Comment: Why closing question? I'm continusly replying to the answers. Do not close this question because I'm still looking for the solution.

Comment: Now that your data structure only uses `parent_id` to relate a node to its parent, can you please confirm that `id` values are unique accross the whole `parentObj`? If this is not the case, then your structure is unreliable. There is no way to know that `childTwo` comes before `childThree`, since object properties are by ES specification not ordered. If you need order, then you should just let `parentObj` be an array, not a plain object with `childXXX` properties.

Comment: Of course the I'd is unique I just modified the original IDs and replaced with unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure does not allow for efficient manipulation:

- By nature objects have an non-ordered set of properties, so there is no guarantee that iterating the properties of `parentObj` will give you the order `childOne`, `childTwo`, `childThree`, ... In practice this order is determined by the order in which these properties were created, but there is no documented guarantee for that. So one might find children before parents and vice versa.
- Although the `id` values within one such `child` array are supposed to be unique, this object structure does not guarantee that. Moreover, given a certain `id` value, it is not possible to find the corresponding object in constant time.

Given this structure, it seems best to first add a hash to solve the above mentioned disadvantages. An object for knowing a node's group (by id) and an object to know which is the next level's group name, can help out for that.

The above two tasks can be executed in *O(n)* time, where *n* is the number of nodes.

Here is the ES5-compatible code (since you mentioned in comments not to have ES6 support). It provides one example call where node with id "1111" is removed from your example data, and prints the resulting object.

```js
function removeSubTree(data, id) {
    var groupOf = {}, groupAfter = {}, group, parents, keep = { false: [], true: [] };

    // Provide link to group per node ID
    for (group in data) {
        data[group].forEach(function (node) {
            groupOf[node.id] = group;
        });
    }
    // Create ordered sequence of groups, since object properties are not ordered
    for (group in data) {
        if (!data[group].length || !data[group][0].parent_id) continue;
        groupAfter[groupOf[data[group][0].parent_id]] = group;
    }
    // Check if given id exists:
    group = groupOf[id];
    if (!group) return; // Nothing to do
    // Maintain list of nodes to keep and not to keep within the group
    data[group].forEach(function (node) {
        keep[node.id !== id].push(node);
    });
    while (keep.false.length) { // While there is something to delete
        data[group] = keep.true; // Delete the nodes from the group
        if (!keep.true.length) delete data[group]; // Delete the group if empty
        // Collect the ids of the removed nodes
        parents = {};
        keep.false.forEach(function (node) {
            parents[node.id] = true;
        });
        group = groupAfter[group]; // Go to next group
        if (!group) break; // No more groups
        // Determine what to keep/remove in that group
        keep = { false: [], true: [] };
        data[group].forEach(function (node) {
            keep[!parents[node.parent_id]].push(node);
        });
    }
}

var tree = {"parentObj": {"childOne": [{"name": "A","id": "1"},{"name": "B","id": "2"}],"childTwo": [{"name": "AB","parent_id": "1","id": "11"},{"name": "DE","parent_id": "2","id": "22"}],"childThree": [{"name": "ABC","parent_id": "22","id": "111"},{"name": "DEF","parent_id": "11","id": "222"}],"childFour": [{"name": "ABCD","parent_id": "111","id": "1111"},{"name": "PQRS","parent_id": "111","id": "2222"}],"childFive": [{"name": "FGRGF","parent_id": "1111","id": "11111"},{"name": "ASLNJ","parent_id": "1111","id": "22222"},{"name": "ASKJA","parent_id": "1111","id": "33333"}],"childSix": [{"name": "SDKJBS","parent_id": "11111","id": "111111"},{"name": "ASKLJB","parent_id": "11111","id": "222222"}]}}

removeSubTree(tree.parentObj, "1111");

console.log(tree.parentObj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: really appreciate your efforts. You've written the code in ES6, So I compiled it using Babel. But the output is not correct.

Comment: *"The output is not correct"*. Please explain. The snippet shows the correct output as far as I can see.

Comment: your program only removes the object whose I'd is passed through the method. But it's not deleting the sub roots related to that object.

Comment: But it is: please check the snippet: see how it deletes all the descendants of the node with id=1111. You must have implemented it wrongly.

Comment: I updated the answer. Uses now the new `parent_id` structure in the question, and uses only ES5, not ES6.

Comment: hey @trincot why does it removed the sixth array, even though it had parent id:11111? suppose we know what object key to remove from like removeSubTree('childFour', "2222");. Will it eases the task?

Comment: 11111 is removed, because its parent is 1111, and so a cascading effect will make all children of 11111 to be removed also, which is at the 6th level.

Comment: It worked perfect. I was wrongly mapping the values last night. I'm accepting your answer. Cheers! thanks @trincot

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the function you use to delete an entry should FIRST recurse, which means run itself on the linked entry, unless there is none. So, in psuedocode

```
function del(name, index)
{
    if parent[name][index]  has reference
    Then del(reference name, reference ID)
    Now del parent[name][index] 
}
```

No loop needed.
And since we stop if there is no reference, we do not recurse forever.

Comment: Thanks for fixing formatting, I am new to answering questions.

Comment: You have the object, please write the implementation.

Comment: Hi s.negi! The reason I didn't write the implementation (besides for being on mobile) is that I'm not sure your object is sufficient to writing it. Each child can have more than one entry, but which entry you want to delete is not present in the references. I'm also not sure entirely that I have enough information about your use case to write it the best way. By providing psuedocode I was hoping to give you all the help that I can, so that perhaps you could write it, being that you have more information.

Comment: In addition, from your phrasing, it seemed that you didn't understand the fundamental operation that the algorithm must do (recursion) and the reason for my answer was to explain it.

Comment: Well the object is well enough to solve the problem. Please let me know if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what it is you want but maybe this will work:

```js
const someObject = {
  "parentObj": {
    "childOne": [
      {
        "name": "A",
        "id": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "B",
        "id": "2"
      }
    ],
    "childTwo": [
      {
        "name": "AB",
        "childOne": "1",
        "id": "11"
      },
      {
        "name": "DE",
        "childOne": "2",
        "id": "22"
      }
    ]
  }
};
const removeByID = (key,id,parent) =>
  Object.keys(parent).reduce(
    (o,k)=>{
      o[k]=parent[k].filter(
        item=>
          !(Object.keys(item).includes(key)&&item[key]===id)
      );
      return o;
    },
    {}
  );

const withoutID = Object.assign(
  {},
  someObject,
  { parentObj : removeByID("childOne","1",someObject.parentObj) }
);
console.log(`notice that childTwo item with childOne:"1" is gone`);
console.log("without key:",JSON.stringify(withoutID,undefined,2));

const otherExample = Object.assign(
  {},
  someObject,
  { parentObj : removeByID("childOne","2",someObject.parentObj) }
);
console.log(`notice that childTwo item with childOne:"2" is gone`);
console.log("without key:",JSON.stringify(otherExample,undefined,2));

const both = Object.assign(
  {},
  someObject,
  { parentObj : removeByID("childOne","1",otherExample.parentObj) }
);
console.log(`notice that childTwo items with childOne are both gone`);
console.log("without key:",JSON.stringify(both,undefined,2));
```